# Need Help on Solving Mixed Linear/Nonlinear System of Equations

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am trying to solve the following mixed linear/nonlinear system of equations. Could someone kindly give me some tips on how I can solve it numerically?

$a_i$ and $c_i$ are known and $x_i$, $y_i$, $z_i$, $r_i$, $s_i$, $t_i$ are unknown. There are 18 equations and 18 unknowns.

$$
a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 + r_{1} = 0 \tag{1-3}\\
a_1y_1 + a_2y_2 + a_3y_3 + r_{2} = 0 \\
a_1z_1 + a_2z_2 + a_3z_3 + r_{3} = 0
$$

$$
a_4x_1 + a_5x_2 + a_6x_3 + s_{1} = 0\tag{4-6}\\
a_4y_1 + a_5y_2 + a_6y_3 + s_{2} = 0\\
a_4z_1 + a_5z_2 + a_6z_3 + s_{3} = 0
$$

$$
a_7x_1 + a_8x_2 + a_9x_3 + t_{1} = 0\tag{7-9}\\
a_7y_1 + a_8y_2 + a_9y_3 + t_{2} = 0\\
a_7z_1 + a_8z_2 + a_9z_3 + t_{3} = 0
$$

$$
r_{1}^2 + r_{2}^2 + r_{3}^2 = c_{1}^2\tag{10-12}\\
s_{1}^2 + s_{2}^2 + s_{3}^2 = c_{2}^2\\
t_{1}^2 + t_{2}^2 + t_{3}^2 = c_{3}^2\\
$$

$$
r_1s_1 + r_2s_2 + r_3s_3 = c_1c_2\tag{13-15}\\
r_1t_1 + r_2t_2 + r_3t_3 = c_1c_3\\
s_1t_1 + s_2t_2 + s_3t_3 = c_2c_3\\
$$

$$
t_1 = r_1 + s_1\tag{16-18}\\
t_2 = r_2 + s_2\\
t_3 = r_3 + s_3\\
$$

UPDATE:
Relationship among some of the constants:
$$c_1 + c_2 = c_3\tag{19}$$

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

Comment: @user1949350 I don't have access to `fsolve`.

Comment: What does that mean, you have to write your own function to solve it (that's the task) or your Matlab version doesn't have it?

Comment: You could use the first three sets of equations to eliminate the $r_i, s_i,$ and $t_i$ altogether.

Comment: I would like to learn the technique that can solve my system of equation to write my own.

Comment: @AFP What *else* do you know about those constants? For one thing, the system has no solutions unless $\,c_1^2+2c_4+c_2^2=c_3^2\,$, and if that equality holds then one of the equations is redundant.

Comment: @dxiv: I updated the relationship among constants in my question.

Comment: @AFP Same question stands, just replace $c_4$ with $c_1c_2$ in my previous comment. If $(c_1+c_2)^2 \ne c_3^2$ then there are no solutions, otherwise one equation is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:   assuming $\,c_j \ne 0\,$, introduce the new variables $\,u_j=r_j/c_1, v_j = s_j / c_2, w_j=t_j / c_3\,$, then dividing equations $\,(10)$ - $(12)\,$ and $\,(13)$ - $(15)\,$ by the respective RHSs:
$$
\begin{align}
u_{1}^2 + u_{2}^2 + u_{3}^2 = 1 \tag{10.a} \\
v_{1}^2 + v_{2}^2 + v_{3}^2 = 1 \tag{11.a} \\
w_{1}^2 + w_{2}^2 + w_{3}^2 = 1 \tag{12.a} \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + u_3v_3 = 1 \tag{13.a} \\
u_1w_1 + u_2w_2 + u_3w_3 = 1 \tag{14.a} \\
v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + v_3w_3 = 1 \tag{15.a} \\
\end{align}
$$
Combining $\,(10.a)+(11.a)-2 \cdot (13.a)\,$ gives:
$$
(u_1 - v_1)^2 + (u_2 - v_2)^2 + (u_3 - v_3)^2=0
$$
Therefore $\,u_j=v_j\,$, and by symmetry $\,u_j=v_j=w_j=\lambda_j\,$.

Since $\,c_3=c_1+c_2\,$, it follows that the last three equations $\,(16)$-$(18)\,$ are satisfied automatically:

$$
t_j = \lambda_jc_3 = \lambda_j c_1+\lambda_jc_2=r_j+s_j
$$

Therefore the non-linear part $\,(10)$-$(18)\,$ of the system has the general solution $\,r_j=\lambda_jc_1\,$, $\,s_j=\lambda_jc_2\,$, $\,t_j=\lambda_jc_3\,$, where $\,\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\,$ are some constants such that $\,\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2=1\,$.

Substituting these in equations $\,(1)$-$(9)\,$ leaves a linear system of $9$ equations in $9$ unknowns which can be solved by the usual methods.

Comment: Thank you for the creative solution. Seems like I need three more equations for $\,\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2=1\,$ to find the unique solution.

Comment: @AFP That's one equation right there, so you only need two more, plus possibly some additional constraints (e.g. positiveness etc) for the non-linear system to be *univocally* determined.